# My node_modules folder is greyed out, how can I rectify that?

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code, node-modules, angular8

How can I prevent the node_modules folder from being greyed out?

After I configured the bootstrap, it doesn't work when I run the code.

[image: image for your reference]

Comment: If U are using Visual Studio, Right Click -> Include in Project

Comment: I didn't find any "Include in Project" option after right click

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you are not including `node_modules` in your .gitignore file. Otherwise, the `node_modules` folder will not be part of your git commits (hence, grayed out)

If bootstrap is not working, that is most likely a different issue. You have an angular project, if you want to include bootstrap do:

1. `npm install bootstrap --save`
2. Include `"node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"` inside the `styles` object in your angular.json file.

If the problem persists, I would suggest to remove your `node_modules` folder and doing `npm install` again (after installing bootstrap).

Answer (score 1):

VS Code just grays out the items that are ignored by your `.gitignore`. If bootstrap isn't working, this is **not** the cause.

You likely do not have bootstrap configured properly. Follow the documentation for whatever framework you're using.

For example, [ngx-bootstrap w/angular](https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/documentation#getting-started)

Comment: Another thing to look at is your global `.gitignore` (i.e. `~/.gitignore_global`) for possible entries.